# Is selection with mouse in the Terminal made by the GUI or Bash?

Tags: terminal, linux-mint

I was wondering recently about Terminal in Cinnamon (Linux Mint): Is selection with mouse (without <kbd>Alt</kbd> key and with) made by Terminal GUI app, or is it provided by Bash inside the terminal?

Comment: I use macOS, but Terminals are not inherently GUI tools. Remember, these tithings date back to the pre-mouse days of “dumb” terminals. So my gut instinct is that a mouse selection of items in the Terminal is controlled by the GUI of the app itself and not in any way connected to Bash itself.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 I think that way too but needed to confirm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Answer is both.

Consider these 2 Cases:

1. Start Terminal and connect via SSH to a remote machine, where Bash is running and you can type and see the Characters.
   Disconnect the Internet Connection.
   Bash can no longer control your terminal.
   Yet you can select (& copy) the Characters.
   **Hence your GUI is doing the Selection**.
   Here is a Screen Shot with Selection made by Mouse + GUI with TMUX mouse mode off:
   [image: Selection by GUI]
2. Start Terminal and connect to a remote machine, where Bash is running and start TMUX.
   Enable mouse-mode while connected via SSH to Bash & TMUX.
   TMUX will get your mouse actions (via SSH + Bash + Terminal according to the xterm mouse Sequences) and work accordingly.
   **Hence Bash & TMUX are doing the Selection**.
   Here is a Screen Shot with Selection made by Terminal + Bash + TMUX with mouse mode on:
   [image: Selection by TMUX]

Both (GUI & BASH) have to work with mouse-mode, otherwise it will be useless.